# Inherit Base Class Error Does Not Contain Constructor that takes 0 arguements

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, inheritance, radix

I am trying to inherit a base class into one of my classes so I can use it's protected functions. The base class is built in VB which is a reference in the project and is as follows:

```
Public MustInherit Class RequestLifetimeCacheBase

Private ReadOnly _requestContext As HttpContextBase

Public Sub New(requestContext As HttpContextBase)
    Me._requestContext = requestContext
End Sub

Public Sub New(controller As Controller)
    Me.New(controller.HttpContext)
End Sub

Protected Function GetCachedValue(Of TValue As Structure)(cacheKey As String) As TValue?
    Dim value = Me._requestContext.Items(cacheKey)
    If TypeOf value Is TValue Then
        Return DirectCast(value, TValue)
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function

Protected Sub SetCachedValue(Of TValue As Structure)(cacheKey As String, value As TValue?)
    If value.HasValue Then
        Me._requestContext.Items(cacheKey) = value.Value
    Else
        Me._requestContext.Items.Remove(cacheKey)
    End If
End Sub


Protected Function GetCachedObject(Of TObject As Class)(cacheKey As String) As TObject
    Return TryCast(Me._requestContext.Items(cacheKey), TObject)
End Function

Protected Sub SetCachedObject(Of TObject As Class)(cacheKey As String, value As TObject)
    If value IsNot Nothing Then
        Me._requestContext.Items(cacheKey) = value
    Else
        Me._requestContext.Items.Remove(cacheKey)
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

The old way in VB is being created like this:

```
 Dim cache = New RequestLifetimeCache(Me)
        Dim cachedDatabase = cache.CustomerDatabase
        If cachedDatabase IsNot Nothing Then
            Return cachedDatabase
        End If
```

I am creating a new instance of it like this in C#:

```
 public WebsiteDatabaseContext customerDB
    {
        get
        {
            RequestLifetimeCache cache = new RequestLifetimeCache();
            var cachedDB = cache.CustomerDatabase;

            return cachedDB;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
```

My class code is as follows in C#:

```
 public class RequestLifetimeCache : RequestLifetimeCacheBase
{

    public RequestLifetimeCache()
    {

    }

    public WebsiteDatabaseContext CustomerDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            return base.GetCachedObject<WebsiteDatabaseContext>("Customer database");
        }

    }

}
```

But I am getting the error 'RequestLifetimeCacheBase' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments on the following line:

> ```
>     public RequestLifetimeCache()
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing passing an HttpContext/Controller argument or something?

The VB is on the .NET Framework and I am working on .NET Core

Comment: It's as the error says `'RequestLifetimeCacheBase' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`. You'll need to pass in whatever args the constructor is expecting.

Comment: ASP.net implementation in .net framework and .net core are not binary compatible. You cannot use a.net framework library that specifically uses .net framework ASP.net features from a ASP.net Core web project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had to rewrite the VB Base class in C# as a temporary measure:

```
 public abstract class RequestLifetimeCacheBase
 {
    private readonly HttpContext _requestContext;

    protected RequestLifetimeCacheBase(HttpContext requestContext)
    {
        _requestContext = requestContext;
    }

    protected RequestLifetimeCacheBase(Controller controller)
        : this(controller.HttpContext)
    {
    }

    #region Generic access to cached value-type data

    protected TValue? GetCachedValue<TValue>(string cacheKey)
        where TValue : struct
    {
        var value = _requestContext.Items[cacheKey];
        if (value is TValue)
        {
            return (TValue)value;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void SetCachedValue<TValue>(string cacheKey, TValue? value)
        where TValue : struct
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
        {
            _requestContext.Items[cacheKey] = value.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            _requestContext.Items.Remove(cacheKey);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Generic access to cached reference-type data

    protected TObject GetCachedObject<TObject>(string cacheKey)
        where TObject : class
    {
        return _requestContext.Items[cacheKey] as TObject;
    }

    protected void SetCachedObject<TObject>(string cacheKey, TObject value)
        where TObject : class
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            _requestContext.Items[cacheKey] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            _requestContext.Items.Remove(cacheKey);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the constructor argument. I think like this (I don't know any VB):

```
public class RequestLifetimeCache : RequestLifetimeCacheBase
{

    public RequestLifetimeCache(HttpContextBase ctx) : base(ctx)
    {
    }

    public RequestLifetimeCache(Controller controller) : base(controller)
    {
    }

    public WebsiteDatabaseContext CustomerDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            return base.GetCachedObject<WebsiteDatabaseContext>("Customer database");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have just tried to do it like this but .NET Core doesn't like HttpContextBase, and also I am getting the error: Reference to type HttpContextBase claims it is defined in System.Web but it could not be found

Comment: Just tried that instead, I now get the error Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext' to 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller'

Comment: I just checked, `HttpContextBased` is not available for .Net Core. I'm afraid your VB project is not .Net Standard. If VB project is a library, re-target it to .Net Standard. Otherwise, target your current application to .Net Framework.

Comment: Hi @swdon, unfortuantly I can't change anything with the VB project. And also we are  working on the .NET Core now. Surely there must be a way.

Comment: Can't think of any. You might have to create a .Net Standard compliant `RequestLifetimeCacheBase` class. You mean, before you tried to inherit, when you reference your VB library, you can compile it for .Net Core?